# bs4 find table by id, returning 'None'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Not sure why this isn't working :( I'm able to pull other tables from this page, just not this one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2018.html",
                   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

page = soup(url.content, 'html')
table = page.find('table', id='team_and_opponent')
print(table)
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: there is no id with team_and_opponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is dynamic. So you have 2 options in this case.

Side note: If you see `<table>` tags, don't use BeautifulSoup, pandas can do that work for you (and it actually uses bs4 under the hood) by using `pd.read_html()`

1) Use selenium to first render the page, and THEN you can use BeautifulSoup to pull out the `<table>` tags

2) Those tables are within the comment tags in the html. You can use BeautifulSoup to pull out the comments, then just grab the ones with `'table'`.

I chose option 2.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2018.html'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

tables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in each:
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(each)[0])
        except:
            continue
```

I don't know which particular table you want, but they are there in the list of `tables`

*Output:**

```
print (tables[1])
   Unnamed: 0     G     MP     FG    FGA  ...    STL     BLK   TOV     PF    PTS
0        Team  82.0  19805   3141   6975  ...    604     373  1149   1618   8529
1      Team/G   NaN  241.5   38.3   85.1  ...    7.4     4.5  14.0   19.7  104.0
2     Lg Rank   NaN     12     25     25  ...     23      18    15     17     20
3   Year/Year   NaN   0.3%  -0.9%  -0.0%  ...  -2.1%    9.7%  5.6%  -4.0%  -3.7%
4    Opponent  82.0  19805   3066   6973  ...    594     364  1159   1571   8235
5  Opponent/G   NaN  241.5   37.4   85.0  ...    7.2     4.4  14.1   19.2  100.4
6     Lg Rank   NaN     12      3     12  ...      7       6    19      9      3
7   Year/Year   NaN   0.3%  -3.2%  -0.9%  ...  -4.7%  -14.4%  1.6%  -5.6%  -4.7%

[8 rows x 24 columns]
```

or

```
print (tables[18])
    Rk          Unnamed: 1       Salary
0    1      Gordon Hayward  $29,727,900
1    2          Al Horford  $27,734,405
2    3        Kyrie Irving  $18,868,625
3    4        Jayson Tatum   $5,645,400
4    5         Greg Monroe   $5,000,000
5    6       Marcus Morris   $5,000,000
6    7        Jaylen Brown   $4,956,480
7    8        Marcus Smart   $4,538,020
8    9         Aron Baynes   $4,328,000
9   10  Guerschon Yabusele   $2,247,480
10  11        Terry Rozier   $1,988,520
11  12        Shane Larkin   $1,471,382
12  13        Semi Ojeleye   $1,291,892
13  14         Abdel Nader   $1,167,333
14  15        Daniel Theis     $815,615
15  16   Demetrius Jackson      $92,858
16  17        Jarell Eddie      $83,129
17  18        Xavier Silas      $74,159
18  19     Jonathan Gibson      $44,495
19  20         Jabari Bird           $0
20  21        Kadeem Allen           $0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `table` with id `team_and_opponent` in that page. Rather there is a span tag with this id. You can get results by changing id.

Answer (score 0):

This data should be loaded dynamically (like JavaScript).

You should take a look here [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

For that you can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [html_requests](https://html.python-requests.org/) who supports Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import bs4
url = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2018.html",
                   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text,"lxml")
page=soup.select(".table_outer_container")
for i in page:
    print(i.text)
```

you will get your desired output